# winutils.exe chmod command doesn't set permission

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

```
> D:\>echo %HADOOP_HOME% 
> D:\Apps\winutils\hadoop-2.7.1
```

Create tmp/hive folders on the same disk as HADOOP_HOME

```
 D:\>dir tmp\hive

  Directory of D:\tmp\hive

  06/13/2016 01:13 PM <DIR> .
  06/13/2016 01:13 PM <DIR> ..
  0 File(s) 0 bytes
  2 Dir(s) 227,525,246,976 bytes free
```

Try to figure out what permission are set

```
  D:\>winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive
  FindFileOwnerAndPermission error (1789): The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

When I tried chmod for this folders it seems work

```
 winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

but ls shows same exception

Does anyone has an idea what is going on ? Moreover, It works for me a couple hours ago but now my spark application fails with an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
```

Comment: it seems problem somehow connected with a domain name , as when I use VPN the problem disappears

Comment: Sounds fairly clear-cut.  The workstation is supposed to be a member of a domain, but has lost its connection.  Presumably it needs the VPN to be up to talk to the domain controllers.  The mapping between a domain SID and a username is stored on the domain controllers, so if you don't have a good connection, `ls` can't look up the username.

Comment: You can still look at and modify the permissions using Windows tools such as `icacls`.

Answer (score 5):

I am quite late here still posting it so it might help someone in future.

1. While setting the permission, make sure you are using correct path for winutils.exe (try to use complete path). For me winutils.exe was in C drive:

   > `C:\path\to\winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\tmp\hive`

> Run the below command to check the permission and it should look like below image ([setting and checking the permission : *click to see the image*]):
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE9vl.png

2. If this is your corporate system the you must be on the same network using VPN or Forti Client or any other tool your organisation has been using

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the VPN tip!

Anyhow, why is it so that I need to be on VPN for it to work?

Answer (score 3):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771040

Looks like domain access issues, please ensure you can access domain and take a try again.

After ensure domain access, below error disappear

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions a
re: rw-rw-rw-
```

Comment: how to fix access domain ? I'm facing the same problem here!

Comment: I'd be intersted as well. Not sure how to ensure or check that I can access domain

Comment: I found a solution for me: I was connected to the corporate network using a lan cable. I pulled the cable, connected to wifi and then it work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late here and I just encountered this issue. Writing this so it will help somebody.

If you are using your office laptop, make sure you are connected to office network and retry. The domain Member of Domain settings point to your office network. That must solve the issue.

1. Log on Windows 10 using local Administrator account
2. Hold Windowslogo and press E to open File Explorer
   3.On the right side of the File Explorer right click on This PC and choose Properties Click Advanced System Settings
3. Choose Computer Name tab and select change to see the value configured.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie here, so it might be wrong but I think you need to add -R in the command as below:

```
winutils chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive
```